# How to measure the accuracy of cosine similarity

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity, fasttext

I'm doing an NLP project that use cosine similarity between n-documents, and i build 2 model. The first model is using TF-IDF & cosine_sim and the second model is using FastText & cosine_sim.

I want to know which model is more accurate, i've been searching for the accuracy metrics but didn't find the answer that i want.

Comment: 'Accurate' for what purpose? You can only score these algorithms with some specific goal, and gold-standard set of desired results against which to check which models perform better. Often, those desired results are created by hand, with a small initial set which then grows as you notice, and add manually-labeled results, for cases that are tough to get right for some or all models.

Comment: I'm using cosine similarity between doc X (Job Resume) and doc Y (Job Requirement), and i've been using 2 model(TF-IDF & FastText). The output for both of the model is different but pretty similar in general. That is why, i want to know which one is more good & accurate for the general output.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Your question is about evaluation: what you call 'accuracy' is actually the performance, i.e. how well cosine similarity matches similar documents. The answer cannot be technical: any serious evaluation requires a gold standard, i.e. very often some examples which have been annotated manually by a human. There's no way to test if an algorithm works with another algorithm, unless one is 100% sure that the latter works.

Comment: You need a gold-standard set of desired results: which resumes *should* be marked as closer to which job requirements? Then, score the 2 (or more) models based on which get more of your probe results correct.